# Testing Doctrine event listeners without database calls

Tags: symfony, events, doctrine-orm

I have setup some event listeners for my Doctrine entities which are working fine, but I'd like some automated tests on these for peace of mind. Ideally these tests wouldn't hit the database to maintain some level of performance when testing.

Here is my code (simplified) for my user entity which makes sure the password is encrypted.

```
// UserBundle/Entity/User.php

/**
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"UserBundle\EventListener\UserListener"})
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    // ...
}
```

-

```
// UserBundle/EventListener/UserListener.php

/**
 * @Service
 * @Tag("doctrine.orm.entity_listener")
 */
class UserListener
{
    /**
     * @var Container
     */
    protected $container;

    /**
     * @DI\InjectParams({
     *      "container" = @DI\Inject("service_container")
     * })
     */
    public function __construct(Container $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function preUpdateHandler(User $user, PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        $this->getUserManager()->updatePassword($user);
    }

    /**
     * @return UserManager
     */
    public function getUserManager()
    {
        return $this->container->get('user_manager');
    }
}
```

All I'm aiming to test here is that Doctrine is firing the event on update and that the method `updatePassword` is actually called on my user manager. This is my test so far but I can't work out how to fire the event without carrying out any database queries.

```
// UserBundle/Tests/EventListener/UserListenerTest.php

class UserListenerTest extends KernelAwareTest
{
    public function testPreUpdate()
    {
        $user = new User();

        $userManager = $this->getMockBuilder('UserBundle\Service\UserManager')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $userManager->expects($this->once())
            ->method('updatePassword')
            ->with($this->equalTo($user));

        $this->container->set('user_manager', $userManager);

       // TODO: how to test?
}
```

Comment: > All I'm aiming to test here is that Doctrine is firing (...) <


Stop here and think for a second, why would you test doctrine code? There needs to be a level of trust, and a border which you don't cross while writing tests. If not, you will end up writing tests for external code, which might (or in this case is) already covered by tests.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue the right way, what you want to achieve is to test that your listener is correctly called when Doctrine fires the update event and not to test that the event is effectively fired.
As veNuker said, you must trust that Doctrine will call your listener when the event is fired because it is its responsibility.

However if you want to test the behavior of your listener, you can try https://stackoverflow.com/a/22830909/2721918

Comment: I don't think it's just testing that doctrine code works... It's also makes sure that your configuration is correctly set up...