# How to test that EventListener has been called on event in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

**What I have:**

I have an EventListener that listens to PreRemove entity event in Symfony.

```
services:
   my_bundle.entity_listener.my_listener:
      class: 'MyCompany\MyBundle\MyListener'
      public: false
      tags:
        - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, entity: 'MyCompany\MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity', event: preRemove }
```

**What I want:**

I want to have a test (functional/integrational/unit or any other really) that somehow checks that when MyEntity is being removed a particular EventListener is being called.

**UPDATE**

I don't want to do it in a unit test, the need is to actually check that event dispatcher will really call that particular event listener to that particular event.

**UPDATE 2**

I thought it was obvious, but it seems that it's not - the solution should NOT modify EventListener or Event.

**UPDATE 3**

I specified that I do not care what the name of the test is: functional, unit or any other.

**UPDATE 4**

The solution must guarantee that test will pass in context of any environment. So, if someone extends my bundles and messes with my definitions I should still be able to validate if the EventHandling actually works.

Also, checking the result of handling is not an option because:

1. EventListener can do absolutely anything - there may be cases where I cannot simply check the result and know for sure that EventListener works.
2. Someone may handle an Event in almost exactly the same way, so that the "result" is the same, but the "way" is wrong.

Comment: What is it you don't trust? That the Symfony Event Dispatcher is properly tested? Or that your application is properly configured?

Comment: Probably second. But, doctrine has many pitfalls and problems concerning event listening. Later, I would like to harden my test conditions by testing that inserting an aggregate(for example) calls the needed even listener.

Answer (score 1):

A functional test is for testing functionality; it isn't intended to test the implementation of that functionality or the configuration of that implementation.

A test such as the one you propose will be brittle and not very useful.

What you probably want is to test the feature that the event listener implements.

Comment: I do not care if you call it functional or unit or anything. And specified that now after your answer. What I want: I want to have a test (functional/integrational/unit or any other really) that somehow checks that when MyEntity is being removed that particual EventListener is being called. And no, it's not the feature that event listener implements and no it won't be brittle.

Comment: The platform I work on is big and many people are working on it. And at any moment anything can fiddle with service definitions, so it's unreliable to test definitions.

Answer (score 1):

check out this :  [Write UnitTest for Symfony EventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830674/write-unittest-for-symfony-eventlistener)

It may be of help, as i had a (sort of) similar issue/question

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this doesn't test anything in context of a concrete environment. Bundle could be extended and messed with, but the test should pass nevertheless. This unit test guarantees nothing.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a compiler pass and add it to the last stage of container compilation:

```
$container->addCompilerPass(
    new CheckEntityListenerRegistered(),
    PassConfig::TYPE_AFTER_REMOVING,
    -1000
);
```

That compiler would get executed last. You could check from that point if your listener is registered properly, and if it is, you could assume it's going to be executed by the Doctrine's Unit of Work.

Comment: "How about creating a test in which you load complete configuration" that's actually interesting. How would one go about doing that?

Comment: How about custom compiler pass that would check the builder?

Comment: Well, this isn't a test, isn't it? You're basically suggesting to write a working code that checks that another working code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want. You want a integration test (to test it on all environment) without modifying the listener, the event dispatcher, etc.

**Solution 1**

When you work on dev, test or prod symfony load different events dispatchers it use the same interface and behaviour but it is different implementations (I haven't check doctrine one).

So you will have different dispatchers for each environment and you don't want to know what happens inside. Let's call this blackbox.

```
Action delete -> [ black box  ->  listener called ] -> listener effect
```

You don't want to look at the blackbox or touch it in any way? Search for the effect that has the listener on the system. Database, log file, mailer, etc.

**Solution 2**

If you allow me to hook into the blackbox you I will sorrounder the listener with a proxy and monitor if the listener has been called on the proxy.

**Solution 3**

Alternative you can use the data collectors from the symfony profiler but you won't probably have that enabled on production.

Comment: I think you understood the most what i want. Basically, dependency injection would be my key ally here(and most of all - that's one of the most useful traits of di), but I can't seem to substitute my definition on the run in my WebTest case. Mb you could offer a solution?

Comment: How can you test a listener was added to KernelEvents::TERMINATE as example?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the symfony profiler?

see [How to Use the Profiler in a Functional Test](http://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/profiling.html)

in the profiler events section you have two tabs with called / not called Listeners http://whatever.com/app_dev.php/_profiler/352211?panel=events